# Xamarin. Forms update list view from another page

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages ... the Main Page contains a list view and a button that pops up a page(second page) for insertion to sq lite. so i have a load() method that gets data from sq lite database and load it to list view. i call this method in Main Page constructor and also in second page after each insertion.

load method in Main Page

```
public void load_Records()
        {

            ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal> chickens_record;
            using (var db = new DataAccess())
            {
                chickens_record = new ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal>(db.GetAllData());

            }
            DisplayAlert("Alert", chickens_record.Count.ToString(), "OK");

            record_lst.ItemsSource = chickens_record;

        }
```

and the second page

```
public partial class NewChicksPopUp : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {

        public DateTime selected_date = DateTime.Today.Date;
        MainPage mainP;

        public NewChicksPopUp (MainPage mainP)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            this.mainP = mainP;
        }

        private void chickenSubmit_btn_Clicked(object o, EventArgs e)
        {

            string record_name = record_name_txt.Text;

            using (var db = new DataAccess())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record_name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record_name) && selected_date!=null)
                {

                    db.InsertChicken(new MyChickenModal { Id = 1, Name = record_name, Age = 0, Weight = 0, StartDate = selected_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") });

                }
            }

//************ HERE I CALL THE LOAD METHOD FROM MAIN PAGE********
            mainP.load_Records();

            PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);

        }

        private void closePop_btn_Clicked(object o, EventArgs e)
        {

            PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);

        }

        private void record_date_picker_DateSelected(object sender , DateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            selected_date = e.NewDate.Date;
        }



    }
```

The problem is that , load method works fine in constructor and loads data to list view .... when i call the load method from another page after insertion, the method is fine since the alert message shows up but the list does not change at all. 
note: insertion is ok since when i re run the app , the new record appear

Comment: You need to update the UI. Do you use MVVM?

Comment: no i dont use MVVM for now

Comment: Okay, easist thing is making the NewChicksPopUp modal, so the code will wait until it disappers, then you can update your ui. I strongly recommend using MVVM cause it magaes a lot of UI stuff for you by default

Comment: is Modal  different from pop up page ? because i am using pop up page

Comment: [A modal form or dialog box (In your case the Popup) must be closed or hidden before you can continue working with the rest of the application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so waht about the alert message .... that alert message is working after the popup close .... it returns the count of list which is correct after insertion ... it shows eg: 4 but listview still shows old 3 ones

Comment: yes, this is because your ListView does not recognize that it's ItemsSource has changed. As I mentioned before, consider recoding your page to use MVVM, this solves many problems by default.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void load_Records()
{
    ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal> chickens_record;
    using (var db = new DataAccess())
    {
        chickens_record = new ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal>(db.GetAllData());

    }
    DisplayAlert("Alert", chickens_record.Count.ToString(), "OK");

    // Setting the ItemsSource to null will refresh the ListView
    record_lst.ItemsSource = null;

    record_lst.ItemsSource = chickens_record;

}
```

This is / was a workaround that did the trick in the early days of mono. I am not sure if this still works but is worth a try

## The MVVM-way

As I already mentioned, do it the MVVM way. Add a new class called xxxViewModel:

```
public class YourPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };


    private ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal> _chicken;
    public ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal> Chicken
    {
        get => _chicken;
        set
        {
            _chicken = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Chicken)));
        }
    }

    public void LoadRecords()
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal>();

        using (var db = new DataAccess())
        {
            var allData = db.GetAllData();
            collection = new ObservableCollection<MyChickenModal>(allData);

        }
        DisplayAlert("Alert", chickens_record.Count.ToString(), "OK");

        Chicken = collection;
    }
}
```

Your Xaml-Code-behind:

```
public partial class YourPage
{
    public YourPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        // Set the ViewModel
        this.BindingContext = new YourPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

And in your Xaml you do this:

```
<ListView ... ItemsSource="{Binding Chicken}" .../>
```

Comment: thank you for reply .... i did try MVVM one and i got no result ... im sure im doing something wrong.... any way about the my none mvvm one ,i added disappearing event on popup and unusual thing happend that when my list is out of scroll its not working and when list view scroll appear every thing work fine ... in my phone after adding 4 items and in tablet after 11 items

Answer (score 0):

To reload list view on the mainpage after returning from add page. On the main page set itemsource of list view onappearing

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    toDoListView.ItemsSource = App.Database.GetItems();
}
```